# Controlling uniqueness in a NHibernate composite-element

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I have the following mapping:

```
...
<set name="Tests" table="InstrumentTests">
   <key column="InstrumentId" />
   <composite-element class="InstrumentTest">
      <property name="TestInstrumentId" not-null="true" />
      <property name="OtherTestId" />
   </composite-element>
</set>
```

I'd like to make InstrumentId and TestInstrumentId unique so the table InstrumentTest cannot contain:

```
InstrumentId TestInstrumentId OtherTestId
 1             TEST1            ABC
 1             TEST1            BCD  <--- NO
 2             TEST1            ABC  <--- OK, different InstrumentId
```

Maybe what I want is imposible using composite-element, but then how should I map this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I need to implement Equals and GetHashCode for the InstrumentTest class.

It's clearly stated on the nHiberntate documentation:

> Note: if you define an ISet of composite elements, it is very important to implement Equals() and GetHashCode() correctly.

Comment: [link to the documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/components.html#components-incollections)